# Irreducible Polynomials in UFD and corresponding Quotient Field

Tags: polynomials, fields

Hello,

"Let $D$ be a UFD and let $F$ be its quotient field. Further let
$f$ be a primitive polynomial of positive degree in $D\left[x\right]$.
From this it follows that that $f$ is irreducible in $D\left[x\right]$ if and only
if $f$ is irreducible in $F\left[x\right]$."

I've shown the forward direction, i.e. irreducible in UFD $\Rightarrow$ irreducible in quotient field, but am struggling to understand how the converse direction would go.

In particular, it strikes me that it might be productive to try and show that $f$ is prime in the UFD since this is equivalent to irreducibility, but I don't know how to show this.  Also, $f$ should have no "denominators" in $F\left[x\right]$ since it's also in $D\left[x\right]$.

Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Being irreducible in the quotient field automatically implies being irreducible in the domain.  Are you sure you don't mean the other direction?  In either case, this is a standard exercise (first show that the product of two primitive polynomials is primitive) called Gauss's lemma.

Comment: Shanest, here's a quick argument for you, if you want irreducible in $F[x]$ implies irreducible in $D[x]$.  Let $f\in D[x]$.  Assume it factors as $f=gh$ in $D[x]$.  Then it factors as $f=gh$ in $F[x]$.  This is actually true regardless of primitivity, which you need for the other direction, as Qiaochu mentioned.  The proof I'm giving you proves the contrapositive, instead of irred in $F[x]$ implies irred in $D[x]$ it argues that reducible in $D[x]$ implies reducible in $F[x]$ which is equivalent.

Comment: Qiaochu, I meant the easier direction (the forward direction can be adapted from a textbook or the Wikpedia page mentioned below).

Charles, thanks.  I had been playing around with that kind of idea, but got turned around about what the contrapositive actually was in this case.  Too many negatives with IRreducible.

Comment: Yeah, once you actually know what the contrapositive is, this is entirely trivial.

Answer (score 1):

This is the famous Gauss Lemma (for polynomials) which says $cont(fg) = cont(f) cont(g))$ where $cont(f)$ is the gcd of the coefficients (this must be an ideal for a general UFD).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29